# Reactjs : Failed to load module script: WIth MIME type "application/octet-stream" for sharepoint webpart

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, vite

I'm using reactjs project for use as a webpart for the sharepoint project. But when i deploy the build project. It give me below error.

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

here is the image of console too.

[image]

I have created reactjs project using vitejs for more understanding.

Thanks

Comment: Most likely the application is not getting the file. Try to open the requested url (the failing one) in a new tab. If you don't see the compiled js, thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

First I restarted the dev server but that didn't worked for me.

Then I used the command `sudo killall node` and then again started the dev server. I don't know why but it did worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issues such as your error when I use table component from https://unpkg.com/browse/antd@4.20.2/dist/antd.js.

My code is ...

```
<pre>
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "https://unpkg.com/es-react@latest/dev/react.js";
import ReactDOM from "https://unpkg.com/es-react@latest/dev/react-dom.js"; 
import htm from "https://unpkg.com/htm@latest?module";  
import { Table } from 'https://unpkg.com/browse/antd@4.20.2/dist/antd.js';
....

const columns = [{...}];
const data = [{...}];

function App() {
    return htm.bind(React.createElement)`
      <div className="App">
        <${Table} columns=${columns} dataSource=${data} />
      </div>
    )`;
  }

ReactDOM.render(
  htm.bind(React.createElement)`<${App} />`,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

</pre>
```

I didn't fix this issues yet. This seems be related with mime script problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).